# Why can a url(http://) without commenting can compile without error?

Tags: c

I found I added some URL in source code but forgot to comment it, but still can compile, and I test it individually:

```
int main(){
    http://localhost
    return 0;
}

gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
```

Which can still compile without errors, and I check c keywords, 'http' seems not a keyword, what is the reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it'll be treated as a label followed by a comment.

So you could later:

```
goto http;
```

If you turn on warnings: `-Wall` it'll warn you gracefully:

```
 In function ‘main’:
:2:5: warning: label ‘http’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
     http://localhost
```